# What is the meaning of"Words are cheap.The biggest thing you can say is ‘elephant'— meaning?

Tags: meaning-in-context

"Words are cheap.The biggest thing you can say is ‘elephant’"

By Charlie chaplin

Comment: It's a joke. Which part were you confused about?

Comment: @DanGetz I want to know the connection between the word elephant and words.

Comment: @DanGetz I want to know the implied meaning of the sentence?

Comment: There is no connection, apart from the fact that elephants are big. It has no more meaning than that: it's a joke, and without context I don't fully understand it.

Comment: That's the thing about jokes; few of them survive an explanation.

Comment: Puts me in mind of *The **longest** word you can say is **smiles*** (because there's a mile between the first and last letters).

Comment: Are you familiar with the sayings "Words are cheap" and "Actions speak louder than words"? If you are, that should help you understand.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a joke, based on misdirection. It starts off "Words are cheap", meaning words don't have much value. Then it starts to say "The biggest thing you can say is", and someone might think they're talking about concepts that can be expressed, how words can't express everything someone might want to say. But instead, he says "elephants". Well, elephants are big, but not in their concept, they're just simply large animals. So he was just being silly. The abrupt change from thinking you're hearing something philosophically meaningful to realizing it's just a silly little joke is what's funny about it.

He also might have intended to joke about long vs short words, and "elephant" is not a very long word.

Comment: Can you say using simple English? (So that I can understand more better)